# Is there anyway to terminate a running function from a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I've tried lately to write my own Socket-Server in python. 
While i was writing a thread to handle server commands (sort of command line in the server), I've tried to implement a code that will restart the server when the raw_input() receives specific command.

Basically, i want to restart the server as soon as the "Running" variable changes its state from True to False, and when it does, i would like to stop the function (The function that called the thread) from running (get back to main function) and then run it again. Is there a way to do it?

Thank you very much, and i hope i was clear about my problem,

Idan :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication between threads can be done with `Event`s, `Queue`s, `Semaphore`s, etc. Check them out and choose the one, that fits your problem best.

Comment: My server runs from main, not on a thread.. you meant communication from thread to thread? or i misunderstood you?

Comment: main runs in the "main-thread", no difference to other threads at all.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the documentation, and some experiments I've over the last weeks, there is no way to really force another thread to 'stop' or 'abort'. Unless the function is aware of the possibility of being stopped and has a foolproof method of avoiding getting stuck in some of the I/O functions. Then you can use some communication method such as semaphores. The only exception is the specialized Timer function, which has a Cancel method.

So, if you really want to stop the server thread forcefully, you might want to think about running it in a separate process, not a thread.

EDIT: I'm not sure why you want to restart the server - I just thought it was in case of a failure. Normal procedure in a server is to loop waiting for connections on the socket, and when a connection appears, attend it and return to that loop.

A better way, is to use the `GIO library` (part of `glib`), and connect methods to the connection event, to attend the connection even asynchronously. This avoids the loop completely. I don't have any real code for this in Python, but [here's an example](http://jcoppens.com/soft/howto/gtk/chat_socket.en.php) of a client in Python (which uses GIO for reception events) and a server in C, which uses GIO for connections.

Use of GIO makes life *so* much easier...

Comment: Okay.. thanks for the idea, ill check it out. Do you have in your mind any other "efficient" way for me to restart a server? tried with while-loop but it didn't work since the fact that the loop waited for connection to move on, which mean that in my way ill have to wait for a connection to restart.

Comment: I've edited the above reply - it was too long to enter in this small box :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't abort a thread, or raise an exception into it asynchronously, in Python.

The standard Unix solution to this problem is to use a non-blocking socket, create a pipe with `pipe`, replace all your blocking `sock.recv` calls with a blocking `r, _, _ = select.select([sock, pipe], [], [])`, and then the other thread can write to the pipe to wake up the other thread.

To make this portable to Windows you'll need to create a UDP localhost socket instead of a pipe, which makes things slightly more complicated, but it's still not hard.

Or, of course, you can use a higher-level framework, like `asyncio` in 3.4+, or `twisted` or another third-party lib, which will wrap this up for you. (Most of them are already running the equivalent of a loop around `select` to service lots of clients in one thread or a small thread pool, so it's trivial to toss in a stop pipe.)

Are there other alternatives? Yes, but all less portable and less good in a variety of other ways.

Most platforms have a way to asynchronously kill or signal another thread, which you can access via, e.g., `ctypes`. But this is a bad idea, because it will prevent Python from doing any normal cleanup. Even if you don't get a segfault, this could mean files never get flushed and end up with incomplete/garbage data, locks are left acquired to deadlock your program somewhere completely unrelated a short time later, memory gets leaked, etc.

If you're specifically trying to interrupt the main thread, and you only care about CPython on Unix, you can use a `signal` handler and the `kill` function. The signal will take effect on the next Python bytecode, and if the interpreter is blocked on any kind of I/O (or most other syscalls, e.g., inside a `sleep`), the system will return to the interpreter with an `EINTR`, allowing it to interrupt immediately. If the interpreter is blocked on something else, like a call to a C library that blocks signals or just does nothing but CPU work for 30 seconds, then you'll have to wait 30 seconds (although that doesn't come up that often, and you should know if it will in your case). Also, threads and signals don't play nice on some older *nix platforms. And signals don't work the same way on Windows, or in some other Python implementations like Jython.

On some platforms (including Windows--but not most modern *nix plafforms), you can wake up a blocking socket call just by closing the socket out from under the waiting thread. On other platforms, this will not unblock the thread, or will do it sometimes but not other times (and theoretically it could even segfault your program or leave the socket library in an unusable state, although I don't think either of those will happen on any modern platform).